How to avoid similar solutions?
I have a problem like this
$x_1 +x_2 +x_3 =10$
let's assume $0 \leq x_i \leq 10$
It is obvious that this problem has more than one solution
For example :
Solution 1 : $x_1 =0 , x_2= 1 , x_3 =9$
Solution 2 : $x_1 =0 , x_2= 9 , x_3 =1$
Solution 3 : $x_1 =1 , x_2= 8 , x_3 =1$
As we can see, solution 1,2 are similar since they both use 0,1,9 but for different variables
How can we avoid these similarities while trying to find all possible solutions ?
My main question is regarding a real problem
you can see in the picture we have 13 buckets (each has 4 numbers)
The solution tells me what numbers are in each bucket.
I forced the total value of each bucket Ascending
look at the solution 2, bucket 6,7 have the same total value = 27
the next solution can easily swap the content of bucket 6,7 and create a new solution (which is not actually new)
same can happen to bucket 8,9 or buckets 12,13


You can add a continuous variable $h_i$ for each bucket $i$ to contain its "hash value", then constrain the hash values to be in nondecreasing order ($h_1 \le h_2 \le \dots$). The hash function just needs to be a linear function of the bucket contents, say $h_i = \sum_j r_j x_{ij}$ where $x_{ij}$ is the model variable that represents the $j-th$ number in bucket $i$ and $r_j$ is a pseudorandom number you pick before solving the model. There's a theoretical chance two buckets could provide the same hash code (making them interchangeable), but it's sufficiently unlikely to happen that I personally would not lose any sleep over it.

you can order the variables:
$x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3$

Works in this example , thanks ,
Please also note the added comment in question if possible
